# Rounding decimal values to nearest integers in a matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

There are `np.around` , `np.rint` and `np.round` which are all kinda biased towards the even values, for example, 2.5 becomes 2 and 3.5 becomes 4.

I want to round the array of decimals so that rounding happens consistently. Like anything >=x.5 would be x+1 and
anything less than <x.5 would be x. 
I can write codes with that logic but are there cool and short pythonic ways to do that?

For example, `np.unique(MyArray)` looks:

```
[0.         0.08333334 0.125      0.16666667 0.25       0.33333334
 0.375      0.41666666 0.5        0.58333331 0.625      0.66666669
 0.75       0.83333331 0.875      0.91666669 1.         1.08333337
 1.125      1.16666663 1.25       1.33333337 1.375      1.41666663
 1.5        1.58333337 1.625      1.66666663 1.75       1.83333337
 1.875      1.91666663 2.         2.08333325 2.125      2.16666675
 2.25       2.33333325 2.375      2.41666675 2.5        2.58333325
 2.625      2.66666675 2.75       2.83333325 2.875      2.91666675
 3.         3.08333325 3.125      3.16666675 3.25       3.33333325
 3.375      3.41666675 3.5        3.58333325 3.625      3.66666675
 3.75       3.83333325 3.875      3.91666675 4.         4.08333349
 4.125      4.16666651 4.25       4.33333349 4.375      4.41666651
 4.5        4.58333349 4.625      4.66666651 4.75       4.83333349
 4.875      4.91666651 5.         5.08333349 5.125      5.16666651
 5.25       5.33333349 5.375      5.41666651 5.5        5.58333349
 5.625      5.66666651 5.75       5.83333349 5.875      5.91666651
 6.         6.125      6.25       6.33333349 6.375      6.5
 6.625      6.75       6.83333349 6.875      7.         7.16666651
 7.25       7.33333349 7.375      7.58333349 7.66666651 8.        ]
```

Comment: For reference, this is known as "[banker's rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)" (among other names).

Comment: @0x5453 Interesting naming! Thanks for the info. But are there ways to avoid such even biased rounding in python?

Comment: @banikr: Note that part of the point of round-ties-to-even is that it's unbiased. So by switching to something else you'd be introducing bias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `np.where`:

```
m = np.linspace(1, 10, 13)
a = np.where(m - m.astype(int) >=  0.5, np.ceil(m), np.floor(m))
```

Output:

```
>>> m
array([ 1.  ,  1.75,  2.5 ,  3.25,  4.  ,  4.75,  5.5 ,  6.25,  7.  ,
        7.75,  8.5 ,  9.25, 10.  ])

>>> a
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.,  9., 10.])
```

Comment: this gives the following error `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in remainder
  m = np.where(m % m.astype(int) >= 0.5, np.ceil(m), np.floor(m))` 

But rounds up 2.5 to 3

Comment: I don't understand: `>= x.5 -> x+1`. So 2.5 should give 3, no?

Comment: Yes, it gives the desired result. But what about the error message? 
`print(np.argwhere(np.isinf(recImg)))` of `isnan` gives blank matrix which means no invalid values in result.

Comment: Replace `%` by `-`. The message still appears?

Comment: using `-` doesn't produce the error message

Comment: So does the answer solve your problem or are there any mistakes?

Answer (score -1):

@banikr, I think that you can use`round` built-in function.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_round.asp) you can read about it.

Comment: `np.round(1.5)` gives 2 and also `np.round(2.5)` also the same. Like I said it is biased towards the even numbers. Are there any parameters in `np.round` to change that behavior?

Comment: The built-in `round` function has the same behavior.  *"if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice (so, for example, both round(0.5) and round(-0.5) are 0, and round(1.5) is 2)"*

Comment: Try ceil or floor functions with some kind of condition: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/floor-ceil-function-python/